# как сделать pull request при уже созданном собственном репозитории?

Tags: git

Я создал собственный репозиторий на гите и делал все коммиты там. Теперь мне понадобилось сделать pull request. До этого я не форкал репозиторий. Как мне форкнуть репозиторий и перетащить туда весь мой проект и коммиты?

Comment: Pull_request может быть открыть с одной ветки на другую. Создайте новую ветку и сделайте pull_reqest  в мастер.  https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-requests

Comment: Вопрос в том, как форкнуть репу, или как сделать ПР?